# Download a file from the web periodically

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an application which on startup (`MainWindow` loaded) starts a `BackgroundWorker`, which on `DoWork` checks whether there is a newer version of the file (DatasSource for an Autocompletebox) available. If so, I download and merge this with the existing file and create a new file.

Now I want to do this on startup and also periodically (like 30 minutes). So I created a threading.Timer [it's a private member in MainWindow class] and initialize it in `RunWorkerCompleted` of the backgroundWorker (as mentioned above). The timer goes to the callback successfully but at the file download code (just a fyi, a different namespace and different class) it just terminates and I can't figure out why?

I have tried `using Windows.Timers.Timer`, `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` but no luck...

Can anyone point me to the right direction? I am open to any solution.

Download code:

```
Public Sub MergeHistoryFile()
  /*Check the directory if there are any downloaded files(.tmp);if there are;just   delete them*/
 /*some code which checks if file on web is modified;if yes download file*/ 
Try 
  Dim waiter As Threading.AutoResetEvent = New AutoResetEvent(False)
  _downloader = New WebClient()
  AddHandler _downloader.DownloadDataCompleted, AddressOf Me.DownloaderFileCompleted
  _downloader.DownloadDataAsync(New Uri(path_file), waiter)
  waiter.WaitOne() 
Catch ex As Exception 
  Throw ex 
End Try

/*some more code which checks if there something new in the downloaded file;if yes merge the local and the downloaded file reinitialize the autocomplebox*/
End Sub

Private _downloadCancelled As Boolean = False
Private Sub DownloaderFileCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs)
    If IsNothing(e.Error) Then
        If Not (IsNothing(e.Result)) Then
            Using fs As New FileStream(Path.Combine(HistoryPath, "_tempDownladedFile.tmp"), FileMode.CreateNew)
                fs.Write(e.Result, 0, e.Result.Count)
            End Using
            CType(e.UserState, Threading.AutoResetEvent).Set()
        End If
    Else
        _downloadCancelled = True
        _downloader.CancelAsync()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663893/writing-file-from-httpwebrequest-periodically-vs-after-download-finishes

Comment: Does this need to be done while the app is running or is this something that will get done on a central server?  If so, you could create a batch program and have something like a Cron job or Window's Task Scheduler to kick it off every 30 minutes.

Comment: When it terminates does it throw an exception? Do you know *where* it terminates? Perhaps you could show us the download code so that we can get an idea of what you're doing. Without that, we'd just be guessing.

Comment: Enclose your download routine into try { } catch { } block and log exception somewhere.

Comment: Yes,this should work while the application is running.I don't want to create another service just for this feature.

I don't get any exception; the program just goes back to the UI and the next time it terminates at a different section

Comment: I don't get any exception unfortunately but here is my download code :

Comment: Does it actually trigger a HTTP request or does it fail to start that.

Comment: When the first time the timercallback is called it executes the httprequest successfully.it just quits at the webclient download async.the next timercallback it exits at httprequest itself

Comment: One problem is that you'll wait forever if there is an error. You never set the wait event except in the success case. In addition, I don't see why you're doing an async call here if all you're going to do is wait for it. async-and-wait has the same effect as calling the synchronous method ... it's just more complicated. Finally, `WebClient` is `IDisposable`, so you should put it in a `Using` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried to use the synchronous way of downloading the data and creating the file;but still no success.I forgot to mention that before downloading the file i check if there are any (temporary files download);if there are i just delete them;that's why FileMode.CreateNew.

Comment: Any solution..I am dumbfounded here. Just can't figure out why is this happening.The code works successfully first time,but the next time its unable to download.

Comment: @SparshGupta: See my answer. It works the first time and then fails on subsequent tries because of the `FileMode` you're using.

Comment: @JimMischel: Hi, I even tried to do FileMode.Create but still it doesn't work; the code just goes back to the GUI without any exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827030/httpwebrequest-times-out-on-second-call

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this code, as I pointed out in my comment.

I think your primary problem is that when you create the file, you're passing `FileMode.CreateNew`, which is going to fail if the file already exists. As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileMode.aspx) says:

> CreateNew Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. If the file already exists, an IOException exception is thrown.

You probably want `FileMode.Create`.

So what happens is that the `FileStream` constructor throws an exception, which causes your `DownloadFileCompleted` method to exit without ever setting the event that tells the caller to stop waiting.